# CSS - Mobile Fixed Positioning: weird behaviour.

Tags: html, css, mobile, css-position, responsive

Im designing a section where I want to have a fixed sidebar next to a scrollable content. It works just fine when I'm seeing in any non-mobile browser, but it doesnt work when using the mobile resolutions in the Chrome's Dev Tools. It starts scrolling the fixed div, but not at the same pase than the other one.

I'll leave you the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="scrollable_content">
      <div class="fixed_sidebar">FIXED SIDEBAR</div>

      <div class="fixed_topbar">FIXED TOPBAR</div>

      <div class="content">

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sequi id unde sunt, corporis qui adipisci expedita facilis ipsa doloremque. Id fuga ad repellat, modi unde consectetur quasi rerum deserunt.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
html, body{
        width: 100%
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }
      .scrollable_content{
        position: relative;
        left: 320px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 50px 15px;
        background-color: #555;
        }

      .fixed_sidebar{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 320px;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: red;
      }

      .fixed_topbar{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        left: 320px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #222;
      }
```

My question is, what am I doing wrong? Fixed positioning just doesnt work in mobile?

Comment: For me Its working fine. Avoid scrolling with mouse and use the tap event to drag and drop(Scrolling behaviour) for mobile environment in Chrome Dev Tools.